# In unicode standard, why does U+12ca = 0x12ca? Where does the 0 come from and how does 0x12ca = 4810 decimal

Tags: unicode, decimal, codepoint

I'm learning about Unicode basics and I came across this passage:

"The Unicode standard describes how characters are represented by code points. A code point is an integer value, usually denoted in base 16. In the standard, a code point is written using the ***notation U+12ca to mean the character with value 0x12ca (4810 decimal)***."

I have three questions from here.

1. what does the ca stand for? in some places i've seen it written as just U+12. what's the difference?
2. where did the 0 in 0x12ca come from? what does it mean?
3. how does the value 0x12ca become 4810 decimal?

its my first post here and would appreciate any help! have a nice day y'all!!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: `what does the ca stand for? in some places i've seen it written as just U+12. what's the difference?` 12ca and 12 are different numbers. `0x` is a prefix to denote a hexadecimal number.

Comment: Note: U+nnnn should have 4 to 6 hex digit (according Unicode standard). Never write U+12 (U+0012 is the correct way to write smaller code points). `0xHH` is the convention on C language (and so on many other languages) to write hexadecimal numbers). Just to distinguish numbers with hexnumbers (and so the user may have the choice on how to write numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. what does the `ca` stand for?

It stands for the hexadecimal digits `c` and `a`.

> In some places I've seen it written as just `U+12`. What's the difference?

Either that is a mistake, or `U+12` is another (IMO sloppy / ambiguous) way of writing `U+0012` ... which is a different Unicode codepoint to `U+12ca`.

> 2. Where did the `0` in `0x12ca` come from? what does it mean?

That is a different notation.  That is hexadecimal (integer) literal notation as used in various programming languages; e.g. C, C++, Java and so on.  It represents a number ... not necessarily a Unicode codepoint.

The `0x` is just part of the notation.  (It "comes from" the respective language specifications ...)

> 3. How does the value `0x12ca` become `4810` decimal?

The `0x` means that the remaining are hexadecimal digits (aka base 16), where:

- `a` or `A` represents `10`,
- `b` or `B` represents `11`,
- `c` or `C` represents `12`,
- `d` or `D` represents `13`,
- `e` or `E` represents `14`,
- `f` or `F` represents `15`,

So `0x12ca` is 1 x 16<sup>3</sup> + 2 x 16<sup>2</sup> + 12 x 16<sup>1</sup> + 10 x 16<sup>0</sup> ... is 4810.

(Do the arithmetic yourself to check.  Converting between base 10 and base 16 is simple high-school mathematics.)